# How to check if a certain port/container/image is in use in Docker

Tags: bash, docker

I'm creating a bash script to loop all my packages, and execute their tests.

```
testAll () {
    dir=~/packages;

    for f in "$dir"/*
    do
        cd $f;
        sail down;
    done;

    for f in "$dir"/*
    do
        cd $f;
        sail up;

        if MYSQL is EXIST; then
            artisan migrate:fresh --seed;
        fi
        test-all;
        sail down;
    done;

    cd ..;
}
```

I need to check if mysql is exist, so I can execute "migrate" command. I could only find functions that display the container, but I need a boolean. So, how can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By exist do you mean check if there is a running instance of mysql on the local system or do you need to check a remote system?

Comment: I mean in the running container.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```bash
docker inspect --format='{{.State.Status}}' your_container
```

This will return `docker` status, running, up, and exited.

Comment: I don't know what is my container. I have over 30 packages and each has different container ID.

Comment: you can use `docker ps -a` command to see the name of your container.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up is the following.

```
if [ ! -z $(docker ps --filter expose=3306 --format "{{.ID}}") ];
then
    # code ...
fi
```